# Android - Save image to SD and then Load Image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, load, save

I've designed quickly a piece of code which loads from an specified URL and then saves it to the SD card, however it is not saving to the SD.

```
URL myFileUrl = new URL( Image_HTML);
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
try {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection(); 
    conn.setDoInput(true); 
    conn.connect(); 
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath+image_name); 
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); 
    fos.flush(); 
    fos.close(); 

    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath+image_name);
    image_loader_view.setImageBitmap(bm);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("Hub", "FileNotFoundException: "+ e.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("Hub", "IOException: "+ e.toString());
}
```

I have tried to make this code as lightweight as possible, and I have also activated the EXTERNAL.STORAGE.WRITE in the android manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things.

When you use a FileOutputStream you have to make sure the directory you are trying to write to is created before you try to write a file to it.  If not you have to create it.  This can be done via `mkdirs()` method of the `File` class.

Next I'm not sure the call to `getAbsolutePath` is required, due to the type of file system Android uses.  I've never had to use it to save to SD before.

I'd try these and see if one of them will solve it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the general pointers, I will mark as correct if either work.

Comment: I solved my problem, although it wasn't todo with the tips you have told me, however they were needed to complete the coding.